# How to delete a whole row if all cells contain certain value?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I try to delete all rows from a Excel sheet, who satisfied this condition: all cells from a row must contain only the values "-" or "".

I use Python and openpyxl .

But my code, don't work well:

```
import openpyxl

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename="testat_openpyxl.xlsx")

instr=""
for i in range(5, wb1["Centralizator"].max_row):

  for j in range(7,49):


    celval=wb1["Centralizator"].cell(row=i,column=j).value
    ins='{}=="-" or {}=="" and '.format(celval)
    instr=instr + ins
 if  instr[:-3]:

    wb1["Centralizator"].delete_rows(i,1)


wb1.save('testat_openpyxl.xlsx')
```

My idea is to create a big "if" statement , to check all cells from a row:

```
 if wb1["Centralizator"].cell(row=5,column=7).value=="-" or 
wb1["Centralizator"].cell(row=5,column=7).value=="" and
wb1["Centralizator"].cell(row=5,column=8).value=="-" or
wb1["Centralizator"].cell(row=5,column=8).value==""
wb1["Centralizator"].cell(row=5,column=9).value=="-" or
wb1["Centralizator"].cell(row=5,column=9).value==""
.........loop until column 48............
wb1["Centralizator"].cell(row=5,column=48).value=="-" or
wb1["Centralizator"].cell(row=5,column=48).value==""
now jump to next row
if wb1["Centralizator"].cell(row=6,column=7).value=="-" or 
wb1["Centralizator"].cell(row=6,column=7).value=="" and
wb1["Centralizator"].cell(row=6,column=8).value=="-" or
wb1["Centralizator"].cell(row=6,column=8).value==""
.........loop until column 48...........
wb1["Centralizator"].cell(row=6,column=48).value=="-" or
wb1["Centralizator"].cell(row=6,column=48).value==""
next row.......until max_row....
```

Comment: ***"all cells from a row"***: Please [edit] your question and clarify, as your code only compares Column 7 and 8.

Comment: Why not read the data in using pandas and rewrite the modified data to the same page?